# Go struct tags in Python

Tags: python, go

Go lang has a feature, that has a name "struct tags".
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Well-known-struct-tags

Does python have something similar to it?
I mean that I want to say python somehow that if I'm using my class in json unmarshalling that it should be filled using one names, and if it's data from db reading that names could be a little bit different.

Go example:

```
struct test {
      TestField   int64  `json:"test_int" db:"TestInt"`  
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with go. Which part here is the struct tag and what does it do?

Comment: Not exactly like that, but you can take a look at how that's done e.g. in [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/).

Comment: @MadPhysicist https://medium.com/golangspec/tags-in-golang-3e5db0b8ef3e

Comment: @MadPhysicist `json:"test_int" db:"TestInt"`  - struct tag. It describes which data (name of the fields) will be parsed and saved into `TestFiled` in case of json unmarshall or read from database.